# Find time interval with groupby and agg

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`df`:

```
          Id    timestamp               data    sig     events1 Start   Peak    Timediff    Datadiff
104513  104754  2012-03-21 16:23:21.923 19.5    1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     28732.920   0.5
104514  104755  2012-03-21 16:23:22.023 20.0    -1.0    0.0     0.0     1.0     0.100       0.5
104623  104864  2012-03-22 04:27:04.550 19.5    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     43423.127   -0.5
104630  104871  2012-03-22 04:27:11.670 19.5    -1.0    0.0     0.0     0.0     7.120       0.0
105147  105388  2012-03-23 06:12:24.523 19.0    -1.0    0.0     1.0     0.0     92712.853   -0.5
105148  105389  2012-03-23 06:12:24.623 18.5    1.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.100       -0.5
```

I want to find the time interval in between the `Peak ==1` rows, where the start timestamp is the first that appears `1` in `Start` for that interval and the end timestamp is `Peak ==1`. There is only one row with `Peak ==1` and may be multiple rows with `Start ==1`

I was trying to group by `df['group'] = df['Peak'].cumsum()`, then use `agg`, something like `df = df.groupby('group').agg({'Start': 'first', 'timestamp' :'first' ...})`, but I am not sure how to specify the start and end  timestamps in each group.

Expected output:

```
timestamp1(i.e.Start ==1) timestamp2(i.e. Peak ==1) TimeInterval            
2012-03-21 16:23:21.923   2012-03-21 16:23:22.023   0.1
                          ...
```

Edit:

Reproducible Example:

```
        Id      timestamp               Start   Peak
51253   51494   2012-01-27 06:22:08.330 NaN     1.0  # Time interval are divided by these rows where `Peak==1`.
51254   51495   2012-01-27 06:22:08.430 0.0     0.0
51255   51496   2012-01-27 07:19:06.297 1.0*    0.0
51256   51497   2012-01-27 07:19:06.397 0.0     0.0
51259   51500   2012-01-27 07:32:19.587 0.0     0.0
51260   51501   2012-01-27 07:32:19.687 0.0     1.0  # Time interval are divided by these rows where `Peak==1`.
51261   51502   2012-01-27 07:32:37.607 0.0     0.0
51262   51503   2012-01-27 07:32:37.707 0.0     0.0
51325   51566   2012-01-27 09:00:23.053 1.0*    0.0
51326   51567   2012-01-27 09:00:23.153 0.0     0.0
51327   51568   2012-01-27 09:00:28.047 0.0     0.0
51328   51569   2012-01-27 09:00:28.147 0.0     1.0  # Time interval are divided by these rows where `Peak==1`.
51349   51590   2012-01-27 09:06:23.110 0.0     0.0
51350   51591   2012-01-27 09:06:23.210 0.0     0.0
51351   51592   2012-01-27 09:06:33.113 0.0     0.0
51352   51593   2012-01-27 09:06:33.213 0.0     0.0
51389   51630   2012-01-27 10:00:32.037 1.0*    0.0
51390   51631   2012-01-27 10:00:32.137 0.0     0.0
51393   51634   2012-01-27 10:06:00.187 0.0     0.0
51394   51635   2012-01-27 10:06:00.287 0.0     0.0
51535   51776   2012-01-27 10:40:48.693 0.0     0.0  # From here onwards are the additional data where an issue occurred. 
51536   51777   2012-01-27 10:40:48.793 0.0     0.0
51537   51778   2012-01-27 10:40:51.697 0.0     0.0
51538   51779   2012-01-27 10:40:51.797 0.0     0.0
51539   51780   2012-01-27 10:40:53.697 0.0     0.0
51540   51781   2012-01-27 10:40:53.797 1.0*    0.0
51541   51782   2012-01-27 10:40:55.700 0.0     0.0
51542   51783   2012-01-27 10:40:55.800 1.0*    0.0
51543   51784   2012-01-27 10:40:56.703 0.0     0.0
51544   51785   2012-01-27 10:40:56.803 1.0*    0.0
51545   51786   2012-01-27 10:40:58.707 0.0     0.0
51546   51787   2012-01-27 10:40:58.807 0.0     0.0
51547   51788   2012-01-27 10:41:01.770 0.0     0.0
51548   51789   2012-01-27 10:41:01.870 0.0     0.0
51549   51790   2012-01-27 10:41:03.673 0.0     0.0
51550   51791   2012-01-27 10:41:03.773 0.0     0.0
51551   51792   2012-01-27 10:41:05.777 0.0     0.0
51552   51793   2012-01-27 10:41:05.877 1.0*    0.0
51553   51794   2012-01-27 10:41:08.780 0.0     0.0
51554   51795   2012-01-27 10:41:08.880 0.0     0.0
51555   51796   2012-01-27 10:41:09.783 0.0     0.0
51556   51797   2012-01-27 10:41:09.883 1.0*    0.0
51557   51798   2012-01-27 10:41:12.687 0.0     0.0
51558   51799   2012-01-27 10:41:12.787 0.0     0.0
51559   51800   2012-01-27 10:41:15.690 0.0     0.0
51560   51801   2012-01-27 10:41:15.790 0.0     0.0
51561   51802   2012-01-27 10:41:17.693 0.0     0.0
51562   51803   2012-01-27 10:41:17.793 0.0     1.0  # Time interval are divided by these rows where `Peak==1`.
51567   51808   2012-01-27 10:42:47.810 0.0     0.0
```

`* - refers to the start timestamp of each time interval.`

So expected outcome would be:

```
timestamp1(i.e.Start ==1)  timestamp2(i.e. Peak ==1) TimeInterval            
2012-01-27 07:19:06.297    2012-01-27 07:32:19.687   00:13:13.390000 (timestamp2 - timestamp1)
2012-01-27 09:00:23.053    2012-01-27 09:00:28.147   00:00:05.094000 (timestamp2 - timestamp1)
                          ...
```

---

Update:

Using

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df['group'] = df['Start'].cumsum()
df['group1'] = df['Peak'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()  
df

mask = df['group1'].eq(df.groupby('group')['group1'].transform('first'))
df1 = df[mask & df['group'].gt(0) & df['group1'].gt(0)]  
df1

df2 = (df1.groupby('group').agg(timestamp1=('timestamp','first'),
                                timestamp2=('timestamp','last'))
                           .reset_index(drop=True)) 
df2['TimeInterval'] = df2['timestamp2'].sub(df2['timestamp1']) 
df2
```

It returned:

```
    timestamp1              timestamp2              TimeInterval
0   2012-01-27 07:19:06.297 2012-01-27 07:32:19.687 00:13:13.390000
1   2012-01-27 09:00:23.053 2012-01-27 09:00:28.147 00:00:05.094000
2   2012-01-27 10:00:32.037 2012-01-27 10:40:53.697 00:40:21.660000 # Should be from `10:00:32.037` to `10:41:17.793`.
3   2012-01-27 10:40:53.797 2012-01-27 10:40:55.700 00:00:01.903000
4   2012-01-27 10:40:55.800 2012-01-27 10:40:56.703 00:00:00.903000
5   2012-01-27 10:40:56.803 2012-01-27 10:41:05.777 00:00:08.974000
6   2012-01-27 10:41:05.877 2012-01-27 10:41:09.783 00:00:03.906000
7   2012-01-27 10:41:09.883 2012-01-27 10:41:17.793 00:00:07.910000
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: @jezrael Sure please see edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need create groups by  [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)  and also groups from back for `Peak` and then filter first groups by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with exclude first and last rows filled by `0`:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df['group'] = df['Start'].cumsum()
df['group1'] = df['Peak'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()

mask = df['group1'].eq(df.groupby('group')['group1'].transform('first'))
df1 = df[mask & df['group'].gt(0) & df['group1'].gt(0)]
```

And last aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) timestamps with subtracting:

```
df2 = (df1.groupby('group1', sort=False).agg(timestamp1=('timestamp','first'),
                                             timestamp2=('timestamp','last'))
                                        .reset_index(drop=True)) 
df2['TimeInterval'] = df2['timestamp2'].sub(df2['timestamp1']) 
print (df2)
               timestamp1              timestamp2    TimeInterval
0 2012-01-27 07:19:06.297 2012-01-27 07:32:19.687 00:13:13.390000
1 2012-01-27 09:00:23.053 2012-01-27 09:00:28.147 00:00:05.094000
2 2012-01-27 10:00:32.037 2012-01-27 10:41:17.793 00:40:45.756000
```

Comment: May I ask why we group by `Start` rather than `Peak`? I want to find the time interval between first `Start ==1` to the `Peak ==1` data point for each interval between `Peak ==1` rows, shouldn't we group by `Peak`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Hard test data if only one group, here is necessary create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (it means copy data and change)

Comment: Hi I just added a reproducible example to my question.

Comment: It was very close but some rows seem to be wrong. Instead of using only the first `Start ==1`, it seems that it used `Start ==1` several times (but I only need the first `Start ==1` and time from there to the `Peak ==1` in that interval). Should I used `mask = df['group1'].eq(df.groupby('group1')['group'].transform('first'))`? Please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: I uploaded some additional data, and updated the issue in the question.

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Last paragraph was changed with `df1.groupby('group1', sort=False)`